# Python Exception instances can be indexed directly

Tags: python, python-2.x

I just discovered that a python exception can be indexed directly very similarly to a `Sequence` type object, like so:

```
>>> e = Exception('msg')
>>> print e[0]
msg
>>> e = Exception(1,2,3)
>>> x,y,z = e
```

It looks like `BaseException` contains methods for example `__getitem__` and `__getslice__` that implement this syntax.

However, what surprise me is that I can not find any relevant description about this behavior in the documentations I can think of looking into, e.g., related sections of [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions) and [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html).

Is this a documented syntax and where is it documented?

Comment: Only relevant to Python 2. In Python 3 `print(Exception('a')[0])` raises `TypeError: 'Exception' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @DeepSpace OK, so I guess it's deprecated in python 2 and removed in python 3.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Looking at the behavior the OP describes it seems like `__getitem__(index)` simply returns `self.args[index]`. I don't have access to Python 2 at the moment to verify though.